# Can't create SQLite table in C++ (android)

Tags: c++, sqlite, android-sqlite, cocos2d-x

I'm making a cocos2dx (c++) android game and I'm trying to implement SQLite but I can't even create a table!

Here's the function where i open database and create a table inside:

```
void HelloWorld::initDB() {

    #if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
    std::string wpath = FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath() + "save.db";

    FILE *f = fopen(wpath.c_str(), "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        firstLogin = true;
    } else {
        firstLogin = false;
    }
    fclose(f);
    #endif

    int result;
    result = sqlite3_open(wpath.c_str(), &db);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        CCLOG("open database failed, number %d", result);
    }

    if(firstLogin) {
        sql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(variable, value)");
        insertVariableInt("coins", 0);
        insertVariableInt("timesPlayed", 0);
        insertVariableInt("highScore", 0);
    }
}
```

And here is my **sql_query()** function:

```
int HelloWorld::sql_query(const char * query,int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**), void* data)
    {
    char* errMsg = 0;
    int result = sqlite3_exec(db, query, callback, data, &errMsg);
    if (errMsg)  {
        CCLOG("SQLite3: %s", errMsg);
        sqlite3_free(errMsg);
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I run my game, **save.db** file is created but there's no table inside, it's EMPTY! (0 bytes). And it gives me NO errors, it gives me just an empty save.db file.

How can I solve this problem? THANKS!

Comment: I'd guess your `firstLogin` logic is wrong. Why are you using it in the first place?

Comment: @CL. I used firstLogin variable to detect whether the database exists or not. If it exists then don&#39;t create/insert values. But if firstLogin equals true, it should create table and insert values. I used it because i dont want to insert values again and again, to the table. What should i use instead of that

Comment: You do not want to detect whether the database file exists but whether the table and its data exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and I could create the `data` table.

```
SQLite version 3.16.2 2017-01-06 16:32:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
data
```

I see you're calling `sql_query` with only one parameter. Did you overload that method or did you define default argument values? Anyway here's the code I use. Note that you can call `isFileExist` instead of `fopen`.

```
MainMenu::MainMenu() {
  std::string wpath = FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath() + "save.db";
    bool firstLogin = FileUtils::getInstance()->isFileExist(wpath);

    int result = sqlite3_open(wpath.c_str(), &db);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        CCLOG("open database failed, number %d", result);
    }

    if(firstLogin) {
        sql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(variable, value)", nullptr, nullptr);
    }
}

int MainMenu::sql_query(const char * query,int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**), void* data)
{
    char* errMsg = 0;
    int result = sqlite3_exec(db, query, callback, data, &errMsg);
    if (errMsg)  {
        CCLOG("SQLite3: %s", errMsg);
        sqlite3_free(errMsg);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i solved the problem. I'm not sure what was the cause. But I made a few changes (using isFileExist() instead of fopen) and it solved.